# How to make Field Plus right align data in IBM DFU?

Tags: ibm-midrange

IBM i V7 R2
I have created a DFU program using STRDFU Option 2. Create a DFU program to edit a file with the DDS below.

```
0001.00      A* FILE        -ICRADEL                                      
0002.00      A* DESCRIPTION -INDIANA COMMODITY RECIPIENT AGENCY DELIVERIES
0003.00      A          R ICRAREC                                         
0004.00                   ICRANUM       15A         TEXT('RA #         ') 
0005.00                   ICRADLWK       1A         TEXT('DELIVERY WEEK') 
0006.00      A          K ICRANUM                                         
0007.00      A          K ICRADLWK
```

When using the DFU application to edit the file pressing Field Plus dose not right align data in the ICRARED field.

I've use STRDFU Option 3. Change a DFU program and tried every likely option but nothing works. I'm wondering if I've done something wrong in my DDS file, or if it is just not possible to right align data when using DFU.

Answer (score 0):

There's no option in the [DDS for Physical and Logical Files](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/i/7.4?topic=dds-physical-logical-files) manual to right align a text field.

I'd argue that doing so is a bug in the first place.  99.9% of the time, right justification in text field in Db2 for IBM i is unintentional.  It's a consequence of an RPG III programmer using the `MOVE` op-code instead of the more appropriate `MOVEL(P)` op-code.

One of the many reasons IBM dropped `MOVEx` from free-format for RPGIV.

I'm not 100% sure, since I don't use DFU, but a quick look at it doesn't show any way to have it automatically right justify a data field.

Answer (score 0):

Keyword `REFSHIFT(S)` will do what you want, but it has some restrictions that might make its use impossible. This will be read by DFU and prevent the user from keying anything but the digits 0-9 in the field. They must also use `Field Exit`, `Field+`, or `Field-` to exit the field. When the field is exited, it will be right adjusted and padded with blanks on the left. You can use `CHECK(RZ)` to right adjust Zero fill if that is what you want. The big restriction when using REFSHIFT(S) is that you can't use `EDTCDE` or `EDTWRD` with it, and it must be a numeric field.